# Read through csv file in s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read through csv file in the s3 bucket but getting error. Seems like something wrong with `list()`.

```
import csv
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='key', token='token', secret='secret')
def open_csv():
    with fs.open('way/to/my.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file))
        return csv_reader
```

logs:

```
csv_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file))
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Comment: use `with fs.open('way/to/my.csv', 'r') as csv_file:` Remove bytes( `b`)

Comment: @Rakesh thanks, it works, please, put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove bytes(`b`)

Use:

```
def open_csv():
    with fs.open('way/to/my.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file))
        return csv_reader
```